# JavaScript method to get unicode values of string

Tags: javascript, string, methods, unicode

The snippet below is from a larger *codeblock* of a project, the  job of the snippet is to *get* the **unicode values** of each character and it works fine execpt from numbers 1 - 9 ( 0 works too ) which return **undefined**.

```
const icons = '$677y8';
for(let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++){

console.log(icons.codePointAt(icons[i]));
}
```

Also, i tried **charCodeAt()** method
it returns **NaN**

```
const icons = '$677y8';
for(let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++){

console.log(icons.charCodeAt(icons[i]));
}
```

Is there another standard JavaScript method to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invoked it wrong, it is [`String.prototype.codePointAt(position)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt).

So you need to pass the `i` th index to the `codePointAt` function as the position of the string to look for the Unicode value:

```js
const icons = '$677y8';
for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
  console.log(icons.codePointAt(i));
}
```

btw, [`charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) is **UTF-16**, where as [`codePointAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) is **Unicode**.

```js
//gets UTF-16 values
const icons = '$677y8';
for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
  console.log(icons.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

Comment: ``` const icons = '$677y8';
console.log(icons.charCodeAt(icons[1]));
/*
for(let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++){

console.log(icons.charCodeAt(icons[i]));
}*/``` returns  **NaN** too